# How to boost results in elasticsearch, so that match in field1 is always higher then match in field2?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is the mapping, 3 fields and 9 documents:

```
#! /bin/bash

#DELETE
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test'
echo
# CREATE
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test?pretty=1' -d '{
    "settings": {
       "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
               "my_analyz_1" : {
                    "filter" : [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ],
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
# DEFINE
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/posts/_mapping?pretty=1' -d '{
    "posts" : {
        "properties" : {
            "section" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "my_analyz_1"
            },
            "category" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "my_analyz_1"
            },
            "title" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "my_analyz_1"
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
# INSERT
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/1 -d '{section: "Bicycle", category: "Small", title: "Diamondback Grind-16"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/2 -d '{section: "Bicycle", category: "Big",   title: "Diamondback JrViper"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/3 -d '{section: "Bicycle", category: "Small", title: "2-Hip Cyclone small"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/4 -d '{section: "Bicycle", category: "Big",   title: "2-Hip Bizzle"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/5 -d '{section: "Small",   category: "Small", title: "Toyota"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/6 -d '{section: "Car",     category: "Big",   title: "Subaru Impreza small"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/7 -d '{section: "Small",   category: "Big",   title: "Toyota Corona MARK II"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/8 -d '{section: "Car",     category: "Small", title: "Hyundai Elantra"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/9 -d '{section: "Car",     category: "Big",   title: "Ford Maverick small"}'
echo
# REFRESH
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/_refresh
echo
```

I want to search for the word "small", but I want always *the order* of results as follows:

1. results where 'small' is in section
2. results where 'small' is in category
3. results where 'small' is in title

So I search with query:

```
curl "localhost:9200/test/posts/_search?pretty=1" -d '{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "small",
                        "fields": ["section^3", "category^2", "title"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

and the results are:

```
{"_id": 7} {section: "Small",   category: "Big",   title: "Toyota Corona MARK II"}
{"_id": 1} {section: "Bicycle", category: "Small", title: "Diamondback Grind-16"}
{"_id": 5} {section: "Small",   category: "Small", title: "Toyota"}
{"_id": 3} {section: "Bicycle", category: "Small", title: "2-Hip Cyclone small"}
{"_id": 8} {section: "Car",     category: "Small", title: "Hyundai Elantra"}
{"_id": 9} {section: "Car",     category: "Big",   title: "Ford Maverick small"
{"_id": 6} {section: "Car",     category: "Big",   title: "Subaru Impreza small"}
```

which is not what I wanted. The 5 should be second, because match is in the section. The 3 should be after 7 and 5, because match was in category and in title.

So, my question is, how can I obtain results where match in section is *always* more important, then match in category, which is *always* more important than match in title.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Problem solved with the search type 'dfs_query_then_fetch', which calculates TF-IDF values across all shards. For more see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `use_dis_max` to be `false`?

This should mean that a doc with "small" in `category` and `title` would be higher than a doc with "small" in just the `category`.

As for the strange behaviour you are seeing between the 2nd and 3rd results, I am a bit lost... Can you do the query and ask for the 
[explanation of how the scores were calculated](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/explain/)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `use_dis_max` as `false` is not producing desired results. It's because TF/IDF algorithm (which is default) attributes lower rank with results where term is occuring more then once (because inverse document frequency (IDF) is higher).

Anyway, I need to change the similarity from TF/IDF to BM25 (or some other). Then I will (maybe) get ranks the way I want. I changed similarity to BM25 but algorithm is still calculating with TF/IDF (do not know why).